# Calling public function in another Controller?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

There are some similiar questions here on SO, but none of them has been answered.

How should i do this, the best way?

I can create a new instance of the other Controller class each time i want to use it's functions, but that seems to be bad in the long run, am i wrong?

Should i make the function (e.g. `UserController.GetAllUsers()`) shared?

Comment: If it's a shared function, why would you put it into a controller and not in your service layer (or whatever layer your web interface sits on top of).

Comment: Well, its not a shared function. And since it is heavily related to the userController i would like to keep it there. As of now, i am creating a new instance of the Usercontroller Class and calling it though that instance.

Comment: It *is* a shared function - the simple fact that you need the same functionality in 2 controllers proves that. And, please, do not use controllers like you're doing, that's just wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest making the method accessible on the other controller.  In ASP.NET MVC, controllers can be created a number of different ways (injection, factories, etc) and you can't guarantee that you will emulate whatever mechanism is being used.

Rather, you should factor out your `GetAllUsers` method into a separate class/method which takes the parameters it needs to return its values.  Then, you would pass the appropriate values to that new class from both controllers.

The class should have no knowledge of ASP.NET MVC; you would pass those in from the controller instances themselves.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I will move all of my functions that are not resulting in a view from my controllers into helperClasses. That would be alright, right? I'm pretty new to MVC, and are just self taught.. so i might have missed some of this ground principles.

Comment: @Anders: That's pretty much right.  It's more than likely that the controller would have translated any query string or form values into .NET types which you would then pass into your helper methods.  The reason that you don't want to create the controller yourself is that in ASP.NET MVC, the controller is usually set up with a `ControllerContext` and just creating a new controller doesn't set up that information correctly.  In creating helper classes, you remove the need for the `ControllerContext`, the controller acts as an adapter between the `ControllerContext` and your logic.

Comment: Thanks casperOne! Very well explained :)

Comment: @Anders: No problem, anytime.